# Python+Pandas; How to proper merge a dictionary of lists of dataframes and save to xlsx or csv as single table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm going to scrape a database which was placed in a public web-site in most user-unfriendly way - as a table with thousands of pages. Each page structure is identical and URLs differ only by page number.

I tried several options with bf4 and pandas and ended up with following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'}

table_dfs = {}
for page_number in range(5):
  http = "https://www._SomeLongURL_&page={}".format(page_number + 1)
  table_dfs[page_number] = pd.read_html(http)
print(table_dfs)
```

This code successfully creates dictionary of lists of DataFrames. 5 items as an example.
Print gives table from each page as a dict element, so code seams to be working as intended.
I also planned to implement `sleep` elements to lower server load, when I will go for full 1k pages.

But now I'm facing two issues:

1. It gives each table in a shortened version. Each table on website have 200 rows, but code output shows only first and last 5 rows of each table. Maybe after proper merging as saving to a file, it will have all the rows?
2. Ultimately I need to get 1 huge table which combines all the smaller ones, save it to a file (xlsx, csv etc.) for further processing. I tried merging, concatenating, converting something, but really lucking some knowledge here as I'm new to Python.

Please help me to finalize this code. How should I merge everything in a single huge table?

Update 1.
To append all the individual DataFrames, I tried to extract each one and then iterate, but print gives only one DF:

```
final_df = table_dfs[0].__getitem__(0)
for page_number in range(1, 5):
    temp_df = table_dfs[page_number].__getitem__(0)
    final_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
print(final_df)
```

I think we are close to solution, but I made a mistake somewhere. Please take a look on this code part above.

Update 2. SOLVED

Instead of append, I tried to use `pd.concat` and it's working. Here is my final code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'}

table_dfs = {}
for page_number in range(5):
    http = "https://www._SomeLongURL_&page={}".format(page_number + 1)
    table_dfs[page_number] = pd.read_html(http)
#pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
final_df = table_dfs[0].__getitem__(0)
for page_number in range(1, 5):
    temp_df = table_dfs[page_number].__getitem__(0)
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp_df])
print(final_df)
final_df.to_excel("All_pages.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. pandas by default prints dataframes only partly. try setting `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)` before the printing the dataframe.
2. try to iterate through each df of the list and [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
final_df = table_dfs[0]
for page_number in range(1,5):
    final_df.append(table_dfs[page_number], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your suggestions! 1st part really worked - all rows displayed. But 2nd part not really or I can't yet get it. final_df is a list, and it says append is not appicable to a list.

Comment: upd: actually, something is wrong with --> for df in table_dfs[1:]: <-- Error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: right. i did not pay attention to your data types. i have provided code for list access (as if table_dfs was a list) but it is a dict in your case. so iterate using `for page_number in range(1,5):` as you have done previously, when making the html requests

Comment: updated my answer to using your data type: table_dfs = {} (dictionary)

Comment: Thank you for supporting me with this, but code is not working for me. Error for append argument -> `Expected type 'DataFrame' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'List[DataFrame]' instead.`  and another error for Ignore Index -> `append() takes no keyword arguments` Does this code work in your IDE?

Comment: I tried to extract individual DataFrame from list and then append them, using `__getitem__` , but somehow it still gives out only single DataFrame, not appending. Please take a look - I added this code in initial post.

Comment: SOLVED! I'm still not sure why append is not working, but with `pd.concat` it works! I added final code to initial post for reference. Thanks, @Octav, for your suggestions.